# Trigger a plugin on page reload in crm dynamics 365

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have an implemented plugin developed in visual studio (we are not using plugin registration tool crm 2016).
I want to trigger this plugin on page reload.
To explain this plugin is fully developped, it loads the contact information to a form onload event.
The idea is that if the user modifies the contact inforation in the form contact, he should be able to reload the form which will execute the plugin.

How can i do this ?

Thank you!

This is the actual plugin which is executed on creation:

```
    AddStep(Stages.PreOperation, Messages.Update, Modes.Synchronous, DlcocontractorDefinition.EntityName, nameof(CompleteCoContractorInformation));
        AddStep(Stages.PostOperation, Messages.Update, Modes.Synchronous, DlcocontractorDefinition.EntityName, nameof(AssociateCoContractorAddresses));
        AddStep(Stages.PostOperation, Messages.Update, Modes.Synchronous, DlcocontractorDefinition.EntityName, nameof(AssociateCoContractorNationalities));
```

Comment: That code isn't a plugin. Also, what does "on creation" mean ?

Comment: It means that on the creation of new record, it loads contact information on the creation of the form @Alex

Comment: Is it possible to add a button which triggers an update event and after that add the plugin on update ? @Alex

Comment: The Update event triggers when you save the record

Comment: Ok, I tried  AddStep(Stages.PreOperation, Messages.Update, Modes.Synchronous, DlcocontractorDefinition.EntityName, nameof(CompleteCoContractorInformation));  and added a button which save (Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();) but it's not working, what you suggest ? @Alex

Answer (score 5):

Unbound Actions are meant for this, they are in fact messages which you can register plugin steps against.

Since Actions can be invoked by the WebAPI, you can for example bind a JS to a Ribbon command to invoke them, and in turn trigger the plugin step you registered against it.

The "old school" approach was to create a two-options field, register a plugin on pre-update with only that field as filtering attribute, and make the plugin toggle it. To trigger the plugin, you toggle the field and save.

---

Since the question was edited and changed radically, I'll add: if you want the plugin to execute on reload, the "old school" approach works just fine: register the plugin on update and onsave toggle the two-options field through javascript.

Comment: Hello I've updated my question, may you please have a look at it @Alex

Comment: @Marwan added a new part to accomodate the edited questionù

Comment: I am beginner in crm plugin, may you please clarify your answer, what do you mean by "register the plugin on update and onsave toggle the two-options field through javascript." may you give an example or modify the code in the question ? @Alex